# Print to video permutations

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

You want to print vectors with $n$ elements, where:

- the first element can have the values: $e1.1, \, e1.2, \, e1.3$;
- the second element can assume the values: $e2.1, \, e2.2, \, e2.3$;
- ...;
- ...;
- the $n$th element can assume the values: $en.1, \, en.2, \, en.3$.

I should print all possible vectors; eg:

$\{e1.1, \, e2.1, \, \dots, \, en.1\}$;

$\{e1.2, \, e2.1, \, \dots, \, en.1\}$;

etc. etc.

Someone could indicate an algorithm making use of while/for loop to print these vectors?

Thanks so much!

---

I try to explain.

I have the need to write an algorithm in such a way that if it is known the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$

I can get the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$

if instead it is known the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a & d \\ b & e \\ c & f \end{bmatrix}$

I can get the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a & d \\ b & d \\ c & d \\ a & e \\ b & e \\ c & e \\ a & f \\ b & f \\ c & f \end{bmatrix}$

if instead it is known the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a & d & g \\ b & e & h \\ c & f & i \end{bmatrix}$

I can get the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a & d & g \\ b & d & g \\ c & d & g \\ a & e & g \\ b & e & g \\ c & e & g \\ a & f & g \\ b & f & g \\ c & f & g \\ a & d & h \\ b & d & h \\ c & d & h \\ a & e & h \\ b & e & h \\ c & e & h \\ a & f & h \\ b & f & h \\ c & f & h \\ a & d & i \\ b & d & i \\ c & d & i \\ a & e & i \\ b & e & i \\ c & e & i \\ a & f & i \\ b & f & i \\ c & f & i \end{bmatrix}$

and so on.

Comment: See [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
mat = {{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}, {c, f, i}};
```

do

```
(m = Tuples[Transpose @ mat]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

To show it's the same as the output in the OP one can sort it:

```
m2 = Flatten[#, 1] & @ (SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ GatherBy[m, Last]);
MatrixForm @ m2
```

[image]

---

The same commands can be applied to

```
mat = {{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}};
```

giving as `m`

[image]

Comment: Maybe so the OP can see this generalizes give him something like: `letterMat[cols_] := Partition[Alphabet[], 3][[;; cols]];` too? And then he can just use `letterMat[n] // Tuples // SortBy[Reverse] // MatrixForm` or something.